# Reference request for properties of amorphous titanium carbide (a-TiC)

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reference-request, transition-metals, solid-state-chemistry

I assume through some side reaction I'm getting $\ce{TiC}$ in my $\ce{TiO2}$ samples after calcination and I need some basic information about the properties of amorphous $\ce{TiC}$.

Is it paramagnetic or are there paramagnetic centers in the powder, i.e. $\ce{Ti (III)}$ species? What is the colour?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titanium_carbide